# Add class on change of menu tab

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add class when I change menu tab. How can I do this?

My menu as below:

```
<div class="profilenavbg">
<ul class="profilenav">
  <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo base_url()."emp_family_info/form/".@$emp_id;?>">Family Detail</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."emergency_detail/form/".@$emp_id;?>">Emergency Detail</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."education/form/".@$emp_id;?>">Education Detail</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."work_experience/form/".@$emp_id;?>">Work Experience</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."emp_join_info/form/".@$emp_id;?>">Joining Detail</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."document/form/".@$emp_id;?>">Document Detail</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."membership/form/".@$emp_id;?>">Membership Detail</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **addClass()** method.

But i don't get your problem, please explain in brief

for more information : http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

you can use .mouseover or .click event in jQuery.suppose you are using .mouseover event than remove active class from each link (removeClass()) and than add active class to current link.

Comment: When I change the link, I want to add active class on that link and remove class from earlier link..

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this, [not tested].

```
$(function() {
    $( "ul.profilenav li" ).on( "click", function() {
       $("ul.profilenav li").find("active").removeClass("active");                                 
       $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Hello everyone, tune the above code if required...